# Starting an internet radio station

Tags: streaming, webcast

I've got a bunch of songs (in mp3 format) I'd like to have friends and relatives in the US listen to, but rather than just sending it to them through xdcc/rapidshare/AIM/Yahoo file transfer/etc, I'm thinking that it would be easier to just make my own internet radio station, ala [Shinsen-Radio](http://www.shinsen-radio.org) and have them listen to that. What software out there can I use to set one up on my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe ShoutCast is what you are looking for.

http://shoutcast.com/download

I used to use it back around 2003. It is a great piece of software.

Answer (score 1):

As Devon said, you can use [ShoutCast](http://www.shoutcast.com/). There's also some other alternatives, such as [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org). If you ever want to consider streaming other media files, such as movies or videos and not just audio streams you can try using [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/). It has a bunch of streaming features that would probably be suitable for your needs.

You didn't mention what operating system you're using, but presumably if it's Windows you can use all three but it sounds like using Icecast or VLC is better for Linux because ShoutCast doesn't officially support Mac/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to be in control of the playlist then you could try out streamerp2p or you can try vibe streamer, Subsonic streaming server & Sockso so that your friends can pick and choose what music you made availble to them. vibe streamer is incredibly easy to use out of the box solution. Campcaster is a solution you can run on linux.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above you would be best trying out shoutcast and I would suggest taking a look at [SMI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smi/) it helps a lot.

> SHOUTcast Management Interface - Create and modify shoutcast servers with the ease of a web based interface. This is a free open source stream control panel for PHP5 enabled web servers with MySQL 4.1 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Streamerp2p,
plus Winamp to play the mp3s, and Edcast encoder plugin for Winamp to create the stream data, which Streamerp2p server then broadcasts. Very simple to set up. Works through NAT/firewalls, for those people who don't know how to configure routers.

It has a built in chat room which is popular for this sort of 'friends' station. There are several stations on the network that have been set up by various web forums.

It uses p2p relaying between listeners, your pc doesn't have to send the stream data directly to every listener, so you can broadcast a higher quality/bitrate stream. With shoutcast/icecast your number of listeners and stream quality is limited by the amount of upload bandwidth your internet connection has.

Users need the Streamerp2p app to listen.

Works on Wine, for Linux users, although the original poster didn't actually mention Linux.